# Handling wanted events outside of the component class in React

Tags: reactjs

I am quite new to React, but need to do something quite complex (for me).

I am trying to find a better way to record user interactions, i.e. "user opened accordion". Currently my code is this:

```
interface ComponentProps {
  eventStore?: EventStore;
}    

@inject('eventStore')
@observer
class SomeForm extends React.Component<ComponentProps> {
   public render(): JSX.Element {
      const {eventStore} = this.props;

      return (
        <Card>
          <CardContent>
            <Accordion onToggle={() => eventStore.recordEvent(EventNames.SOME_EVENT_NAME)}>
            ...
            </Accordion>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      );
   }
}
```

I have many classes like this and every time I have to inject the `eventStore` and for each button or any other element that I wish to record, I have to add the event handler. I am wondering if there is a better way of doing it, so that I do not have to do all of this. I would just like to specify the event name for each element recorded, pass it on when interacted with and all other logic is located somewhere else. Can this be done some way through props? Or using wrappers...?

I hope all this makes sense and I am not trying to do something impossible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a handler on a common ancestor and identify elements inside the handler by, for instance, custom `data-` attributes. Then handle it as you need.

[Here is an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-dream-mb0zs?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)